# Null field returning required

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I set a referral field on my django model to null but everytime I try to register without passing in a parameter it says that the field is required for registration. I've tried different approaches to try to solve it but still no fix. I want users to be able to register without using a referral code

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, address, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(('The given username must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, address=address, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False, True,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, default='username')
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Pictures', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    referred_users_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #subscription_start_dates = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #subscription_end_dates = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    def get_full_name(self):
      return self.email 
    def get_short_name(self):
      return self.email
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
      return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
      return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
      return self.is_admin
```

```
#serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
from allauth.utils import get_username_max_length
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer
from .models import User


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    referral_code = serializers.CharField(required=False, write_only=True)

    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'referral_code': self.validated_data.get('referral_code', None),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])

        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        referral_code = self.cleaned_data.get('referral_code')

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        print(referral_code)

        if referral_code and referral_code.strip():
            referred_by = User.objects.filter(referral_code=referral_code).first()
            if referred_by:
                user.referred_by = referred_by
                referred_by.referred_users_count += 1
                referred_by.save()

        user.save()
        return user



class UserDetailsSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['username','email','profile_picture','first_name', 'last_name'] #'subscription_start_dates', 'subscription_end_dates']
        read_only_fields = ['username','email',]#' subscription_end_dates', 'subscription_start_dates'
        model = User
```

whenever I send my JSON data like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "string",
  "last_name": "string",
  "email": "userandr@example.com",
  "username": "userandr",
  "referral_code": " ",
  "password1": "stringx200",
  "password2": "stringx200"
}
```

it returns

```
{
  "referral_code": [
    "This field may not be blank."
  ]
}.
```

How do I fix this?

I was asked to add the latest migration file :

```
# Generated by Django 4.1.1 on 2024-02-28 20:27

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('Account', '0004_user_first_name_user_last_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='referral_code',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='referred_by',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='referred_users_count',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Did you have `blank=True, null=True` on that field when the model was originally created, or did you add it later?

Comment: can you please add the latest migrations file?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes I had it there from the start

Comment: @Tanveer sure I'd add the latest migration file

Comment: send payload without referral_code, or with data

Comment: @Tanveer still the same error

Comment: `referral_code = serializers.CharField()` set like this in serializers and try again

Comment: @Tanveer fixed it already, posted the answer also. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you are using `unique=True`, in that case it can't save multiple null values. Remove `unique=True` and run migration again.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: This didnt work

Answer (score 0):

So the error was caused by the referral code field from the serializer

```
referral_code = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
```

I changed it to that and now it works perfectly